# Ajax POST function not running successfully with Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, post, alert

I am trying to run the Ajax POST function. But I am not able to see any alert message after completion of the function.

```
 function SendData()
  {

 $.ajax({
       url :  window.location.href,// the endpoint,commonly same url
       type : "POST", // http method
       data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken, 
       lastMessage : lastMessage,
       NewMessage : NewMessage
 }, // data sent with the post request

 // handle a successful response
 success : function(json) {
 console.log(json); // another sanity check
 //On success show the data posted to server as a message
 alert('User : '+json['lastMessage'] +' . User : '+ json['NewMessage']); ***//Not showing this alert***

 },

 // handle a non-successful response
 error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
 console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
 }
 });
}
```

I am calling the SendData() function from another function KepPress() that runs when the 'enter' key is pressed. Data in 'lastMessage' and 'NewMessage' are received from input type text tag in HTML.

Also, I am getting the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at SendData ((index):128)
>       at HTMLDocument.keyPress ((index):162

Comment: console.log output ?

Comment: If you are not getting any alert check of console logs in error function?

Comment: There's no output in the console as well.

Comment: any errors in the backend?

Comment: @zabusa No errors.

Comment: @TeeKay the api is hitting the backend server and the api is returning 200 http status?

Comment: check the network panel in browser.any response from the server?

Comment: @js_noob Yes. HTTP/1.1 200

Comment: Is your error console.log being run? Can you see any output on console?

Comment: try calling the api keeping the network tab open and heck for preview.. are you getting the desired data you are sending from server?

Comment: @zabusa I am getting errors. I have edited the post. Kindly have a look.

Comment: include the jquery plugin in your html

Comment: @zabusa I added <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">. It gives an error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @TeeKay `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @zabusa   Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45‌​g='). The digest must be a valid, base64-encoded value.

Comment: @zabusa   Actually i already have functions in the script tag. Can i also add a src?

Comment: remove the integrity attribute

Comment: @zabusa Still doesn't work.